# Make text editing easier in SharePoint

Tags: office-web-apps, rich-text, multiline-text-field

I'm working on SharePoint enterprise 2013.
Some of my users who are permanently work with TEXT or Rich text fields face with some problems which I couldn't solve yet:

- They need to paste **large amount of text** in a **Multiple line of
  text** column but most of the time the last paragraph *disappear*.
- They need to select **specific words** in the middle of paragraph but
  it is really hard selected (Even in Word Web App)
- When they push **Backspace** button they return to **previous page**
  (This a public problem)

I looked for an App so maybe it makes Text editing in SP easier, but I didn't find anything and there was no one with same problem.
if anyone can guide me or share experience I would appreciate.

Comment: I have had pasting work strange. It will sometimes paste only part of what I copied, or duplicate a section of it, or insert a paragraph break at the beginning or end. I use plain text whenever I can, to avoid this.  But I've never had a backspace force me off the page while my cursor was inside a multiple line of text field.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the experience. The problem about plain text is there is no text editing tool in that field and my users need it. If you had something about enhance rich text I also will appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there are multiple issues here.  Editing text in a SharePoint list form is different than in the Word Web App.

There are no settings you can change in regards to the Office Web Apps.  You can check and make sure you are running the latest patches on your servers to be sure you getting the latest experience.

Latest Office Updates:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn789213(v=office.14).aspx

Inside SharePoint - the options available to the "Multiple lines of text" column type are different based on whether it's a list or document library.  Inside the library there is a check box to "Allow unlimited length".  This option is not available on list items, and it's implicitly set.  So if you are pasting this text into a column that is part of a document library check that option on the column settings.

Comment: Thanks for answer, It was new for me that the multiple line has specific setting in libraries but of course it is in a custom list. Do you have any experience regarding the backspace? Maybe it works as a short-cut but I am not sure how much it's true.

Comment: No - the backspace should work when in an editing context, but if you click out of the TXT box or focus is changed it will go back to browser behavior, which makes it act like back button.

Comment: thanks! I just checked and it worked and when I click out if TXT it brings me back to previous page.

Answer (score 0):

Are talking about which version of SharePoint Tools? It is Enterprise or Foundation?

I've never heard about this... this would be probably addressed by some hotfix/patch from MS.

I would highly recommend you to check your sharepoint version and look for missing patches and updates. I've just tried it in my environment and even a huge "lorem ipsum" copy/pasted worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks for answer! we are SharePoint 2013 enterprise and honestly I am wonder of the attitude but it's really happening! Didn't you have any experience such backspace to react as Back in browser?

Comment: This backspace behavior is usually related to your text field "loosing focus". Have you tried to reproduce this issue in different browsers? IE/FF/Chrome?

Comment: No I didn't know that. I will check and let you know.